# Why does a read-only textbox not return any data in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, readonly

I've set a textbox to read-only. When the user clicks on it, a calendar is displayed and the user selects the date which inputs into the read-only textbox.

But when I try to enter the data into the database, it shows null value. What is wrong?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is a little bit of strangeness when it comes to the ASP.NET `Readonly` property and the `readonly` attribute of an HTML input element.  Rather than setting the `Readonly` property of the web control try simply adding the HTML attribute to the control like this:

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

This will make the control read-only in the client's browser yet still allow you to retrieve the value of the input when it posts back to the server.

Comment: Unbelievable! I've lost 2 hours tonight around this trouble...damn!

Comment: Wasn't working still. Simple mistake: Had to clear cache of the browser to reload the new code

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect!

Comment: Did not work for me! Still not able to get value from the textbox

Comment: Great @Andrew...very elegant solution.

Comment: I know it is quite old but there is still no change in aspx. Set readonly with javascript is working as well.  Sample:               document.getElementById('<% =TxtEndPrice1.ClientID %>').setAttribute("readonly", true); The user cannot hange it but on postback the values are there

Answer (score 3):

The system assumes that read only or disabled controls won't be changed clientside so it doesn't post the changed value back to the server. You need to set the client side readonly property rather than the serverside version.

Comment: Just as a note- actually the values ARE posted to the server by the user browser, but they are not deserialized..

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET assumes that the Readonly and Enabled="false" property of the webcontrol will not change . Thus it does not postback the value as mentioned by tom above . You can use this workaround . Adding this to the html you don have to worry about Readonly property or disabled control  .

```
   onkeydown="return false;"
```

Comment: I also suggest adding onpaste="return false;" or users can still paste things into the field. And you may also want to prevent the IE clear button from being displayed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13481577/74585

Answer (score -1):

Or you can replace the ASP textbox with input type text with runat="Server" and then adding readonly property as readonly. Check the link

[Workarounds to access the Readonly Textbox value on server side when changed through client side script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106000/accessing-the-textbox-value-modfied-by-the-javascript-with-readonly-property-true)