# OnClick event is unable to retrieve controls' inner text in AspxWebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know it's a common problem, but here I am not able to figure out why after a OnClick event, I am unable to retrieve controls' inner text.

Please have a look at this Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
    <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="MyCallbackPanel" ClientInstanceName="MyCallbackPanel" OnCallback="MyCallbackPanel_Callback">
    <PanelCollection>
        <dx:PanelContent>
            <dx:ASPxPopupControl ClientInstanceName="MyPopup" ID="AggiungiServiziPopup" runat="server">
                <ContentCollection>
                    <dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server">

                        <dx:ASPxFormLayout runat="server" ID="ASPxFormLayout1" Width="100%" ClientInstanceName="FormLayout_AggiungiServizi" Font-Bold="true">
                            <Items>
                                <dx:LayoutItem Caption="This is an example" VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                    <SpanRules>
                                        <dx:SpanRule ColumnSpan="1" RowSpan="1" BreakpointName="S"></dx:SpanRule>
                                        <dx:SpanRule ColumnSpan="2" RowSpan="1" BreakpointName="M"></dx:SpanRule>
                                    </SpanRules>
                                    <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                        <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="100%" />
                                        </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                    </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                </dx:LayoutItem>

                                <dx:LayoutItem Caption="This is an example" VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                    <SpanRules>
                                        <dx:SpanRule ColumnSpan="1" RowSpan="1" BreakpointName="S"></dx:SpanRule>
                                        <dx:SpanRule ColumnSpan="2" RowSpan="1" BreakpointName="M"></dx:SpanRule>
                                    </SpanRules>
                                    <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                        <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Text2" runat="server" Width="100%" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="WhiteSmoke"/>
                                        </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                    </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                </dx:LayoutItem>

                                <dx:LayoutItem Caption="This is an example" VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                    <SpanRules>
                                        <dx:SpanRule ColumnSpan="1" RowSpan="1" BreakpointName="S"></dx:SpanRule>
                                        <dx:SpanRule ColumnSpan="2" RowSpan="1" BreakpointName="M"></dx:SpanRule>
                                    </SpanRules>
                                    <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                        <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Text3" runat="server" Width="100%" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                                        </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
                                    </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                                </dx:LayoutItem>

                            </Items>
                        </dx:ASPxFormLayout>

                        <div class="rightButton">
                            <dx:ASPxButton runat="server" ID="MyButton" Text="Aggiorna" OnClick="MyButton_Click" AutoPostBack="false" />
                        </div>
                    </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                </ContentCollection>
            </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
        </dx:PanelContent>
    </PanelCollection>
</dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

and its code-behind:

```
protected void MyCallbackPanel_Callback(object sender, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
    Text1.Text = "foo";
    Text2.Text = "bar";
    Text3.Text = "hello"
}

 protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string debug1 = Text1.Text; // this is ""
    string debug2 = Text2.Text; // this is ""
    string debug3 = Text3.Text; // this is ""
 }
```

I have a simple JavaScript code performing the following operation: `MyCallbackPanel.PerformCallback();`, this should (and does) triggers `MyCallbackPanel_Callback`, populating the `TextBox`es, but when the user clicks on `MyButton` triggering `MyButton_Click`, the Text is always null. I am not being able to understand why or how to fix it, but it has to do with the Callback which unfortunately seems tricky to remove.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect this is page life cycle related. If you put a break point in each method, which is hit first?

Comment: This is because textboxes are readonly. Please see this: [textboxes-lose-value-on-postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869453/textboxes-lose-value-on-postback) . May need change to work with devexpress textbox.

Comment: Continued from last comment: Setting readonly property to readonly has no effect on devexpress texboxes. Try this :  `string debug1 = Request.Form[Text1.UniqueID];`

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh wow thank you so much, it worked flawlessly. Also thanks to Matt Evans for their time.