# Get the textbox value from readonly gridview

Tags: gridview, textbox, asp.net-4.0, readonly

I have a gridview on which Item template has few textbox, due to business requirement I have to disable those textbox.
Now, I have to read the textbox value from code behind. Could you tel me if that is possible to get read only textbox value from gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to not set the `ReadOnly` property on the control in design mode.

A similar question exists:

[Workarounds to access the Readonly Textbox value on server side when changed through client side script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106000/workarounds-to-access-the-readonly-textbox-value-on-server-side-when-changed-thr)

Also, additionally you may want to check out the following:

[How to get readonly textbox value in codebehind or CS file](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-get-readonly-textbox-value-in.html)

[How to get the readonly textbox value on the server](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-get-the-readonly-textbox-value-on-the-server.aspx)

Hope it helps!