# How can I disable the clear button that IE10 inserts into textboxes?

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer-10

How can I disable the new functionality in Internet Explorer 10 that shows a little 'x' in a textbox when it's focused and I have content in it?

[image: IE10 Clear Button]

Comment: They keep adding and adding stuff... Good idea, but...

Comment: How could they possibly think this is a good idea? I had no idea what it did the first time I saw it and I'm a developer...

Comment: Not in the spec so it shouldn't be there

Comment: Such an unbelievably terrible feature. When displaying numbers with right align - you go to click at a certain position in the number, but the cursor ends up somewhere else because this clear button shifts the text over to the left! IE is an embarrassment to MS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove IE10's "clear field" X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
Are there similar methods available for other form elements?

Comment: FYI: This only works only when the browser is IE10 mode and not compatibility mode. grrr!!

Comment: So annoying that this is the case. Compat mode should strip them out... ARGH!

Comment: Does anyone know, how to fix this for IE9?

Comment: @ScottSelby: maybe users will really like it, and all the other browsers will implement it. The HTML spec doesn't define how form fields should be rendered (I don't think). Nobody seemed to mind when iOS Safari's URL field added an "x" icon to clear that.

Comment: It's better to set the `width` and `height` to `0px`. Otherwise, IE10 ignores the padding defined on the field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739092/3163075

Comment: Effective as it can be used in global css.

Answer (score 19):

In **IE 10+**, text inputs (input[type=text]) show a (x) button on the right-side on the field once you start typing, it's used to clear/remove the entered text value.

In **Chrome**, search inputs (input[type=search]) show a similar button.

If you prefer to remove either of them for IE10+ and/or Chrome. You can add the style below to hide this button from the input.

*See it in action...*
http://codepen.io/sutthoff/pen/jqqzJg

```
/* IE10+ */
::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

/* Chrome */
::-webkit-search-decoration,
::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
::-webkit-search-results-button,
::-webkit-search-results-decoration { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Comment: A more verbose answer would help future readers understand better.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input::-ms-clear{
   display:none;
}
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the style and CSS solutions don't work when a page runs in compatibility view. I'm assuming that this is because the clear button was introduced after IE7, and so the IE7 renderer used in compatibility view doesn't see ::-ms-clear as a valid style heading.