# how to remove Cross sign in TextBox in IE 10..?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i am using win8 and IE 10 , in this Browser i want remove Cross sign as shown in image (auto clear sign) in my web page. can any one help ...????

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Refeer this , it can help to to understand question more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481577/how-can-i-disable-the-clear-button-that-ie10-inserts-into-textboxes

Comment: Since this isn't their website, I would assume it's a browser option they're wondering about, not really a code related question

Comment: i just give that screen shot of gmail for an example..

Answer (score 3):

have this.

```
 ::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
 }
```

Comment: i tried it but it not works , can you please give full example of it,

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481577/how-can-i-disable-the-clear-button-that-ie10-inserts-into-textboxes):

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it not works , can you please give full example of it,

Comment: do you understand what CSS is?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do by setting the CSS

```
::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```