# IE 10 close event on select-all

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have an event hooked to backspace keyup on a textbox. I see in IE10 that on select-all you get a close icon. How do I detect that with jquery?

I want to detect event 'Press of (X)' inside the textbox.

[image]

Comment: A "close icon"? That looks like a calendar icon to me. Or do you mean the X? Are you trying to detect whether an icon exists, or whether all of the text in the textbox is selected, or...?

Comment: Why do you need to detect it?  Leave it be?

Comment: If you want to hide it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481577/how-can-i-disable-the-clear-button-that-ie10-inserts-into-textboxes

Comment: Your update is still a bit vague. Are you saying you want to detect when the user clicks the X?

Comment: @Brad i have a filter attached to this textbox. When user removes all the text, I gotta remove the filter. I have a backspace keyup even attached, need to detect this one now.

Comment: @change, You should detect the textbox value change instead, since that is what you really want.  Someone can clear this textbox without backspace.  Cut, for example.

Comment: I cannot put it on change because everytime user will change the minute or date (before he has selected the final value he wants), the change event will be triggered. So at this moment I am using a backspace. Will be dealing with 'cut' soon.

Comment: What do you mean with "filter"? What does it do?

Comment: filter table rows between start and end date. That is not the point. If i Have to detect this event, is there a way to. Or else I can just disable it.